# Ошибка загрузки через widget-fileinput. Как исправить?

Tags: yii2

Загрузка фото происходит, но картинка сохраняется только в блоге в админке в миниатюре, где 'SmallImage' и все, а на фронтеде её не видно и в нормальном разрешении только в 'jpg' почему-то если загружать, а в 'svg' -в большом размере и выдаёт ошибку:[image: 1]

Blog.php

```html
<?php

namespace common\models;

use common\components\behaviors\StatusBehavior;
use Yii;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\db\Expression;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use kartik\widgets\FileInput;
use kartik\widgets\ActiveForm;
use app\models\UploadForm;
use yii\imagine\Image;
use yii\helpers\FileHelper;
use yii\grid\GridView;






/**
 * This is the model class for table "blog".
 *
 * @property integer $id


 * @property string $title
 * @property string $image
 * @property string $text
 * @property string $date_create
 * @property string $date_update
 * @property string $url
 * @property integer $status_id
 * @property integer $sort
 * @package common\models

 */
   class Blog extends ActiveRecord {

  const STATUS_LIST = ['off','on'];
   /* public $tags_array;*/
   public $tags_array;
   public $file;
   

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'blog';
    }


    public function behaviors()
    {
         return [
         'timestampBehavior'=>[
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'createdAtAttribute' => 'date_create',
            'updatedAtAttribute' => 'date_update',
            'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
            ],
            'statusBehavior'=> [
            'class' => StatusBehavior::className(),
            'statusList'=> self::STATUS_LIST,
              ]
         ];
      }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['title', 'url'], 'required'],
            [['text'], 'string'],
            [['url'], 'unique'],
            [['status_id', 'sort'], 'integer'],
            [['sort'], 'integer','max'=>99, 'min'=>1],
            [['title', 'url'], 'string', 'max' => 150],
            [['image'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['image'], 'file', 'extensions'=>'jpg, gif, png'],
            [['tags_array','date_create','date_update'],'safe'],

        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'title' => 'Заголовок',
            'text' => 'Текст',
            'url' => 'ЧПУ',
            'status_id' => 'Статус',
            'sort' => 'Сортировка',
            'date_update' => 'Обновлено',
            'date_create' => 'Создано',
            'tags_array' => 'Тэги',
            'tagsAsString' => 'Тэги',
            'image' => 'Картинка',
            'file' => 'Картинка',
            'author.username'=>'Имя Автора',
            'author.email'=>'Почта Автора',

        ];
    }

    public function getAuthor () {
      return $this->hasOne (User::className(),['id'=>'user_id']);
    
    }

     public function getBlogTag () {
      return $this->hasMany(BlogTag::className(),['blog_id'=>'id']);
    }

      public function getTags()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Tag::className(),['id'=>'tag_id'])->via('blogTag');
    }

      public function getTagsAsString() 
    {  
       $arr = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($this->tags,'id','name');
       return implode (', ',$arr);
    }


 public function getSmallImage() 
    {  
      if($this->image){
        $path = str_replace('admin.','',Url::home(true)).'uploads/images/blog/50x50/'.$this->image;
      }else{

        $path = str_replace('admin.','', Url::home(true)).'uploads/images/pic.svg';
      } 
      return $path;
     }

       public function afterFind() 
    {  
      parent::afterFind();
      $this->tags_array = $this->tags;
    }


 public function beforeSave ($insert)

{  
  if ($file = UploadedFile::getInstance($this,'file')) {
      $dir = Yii::getAlias('@images').'/blog/';

  if (!is_dir($dir . $this->image)) {
  if (file_exists($dir.$this->image)){
     unlink($dir.$this->image);
  }
  if (file_exists($dir.'50x50/'.$this->image)) {
     unlink($dir.'50x50/'.$this->image);
  }
  if (file_exists($dir. '800x/'.$this->image)) {
     unlink($dir.'800x/'.$this->image);
  }
}
    $this->image = strtotime ('now').'_'.Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString(6) .'.'. $file->extension;
    $file ->saveAs($dir.$this->image);
    $imag = Yii::$app->image->load($dir.$this->image);
    $imag ->background ('#fff',0);
    $imag ->resize ('50','50', Yii\image\drivers\Image::INVERSE);
    $imag ->crop ('50','50');
    $imag ->save($dir.'50x50/'.$this->image, 90);
    $imag = Yii::$app->image->load($dir.$this->image);
    $imag->background('#fff',0);
    $imag->resize('800',null, Yii\image\drivers\Image::INVERSE);
    $imag->save($dir.'800x/'.$this->image, 90);

    }
      return parent::beforeSave($insert);
  }


   public function afterSave ($insert, $changedAttributes) 
    {
      parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);

      $arr = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($this->tags,'id','id');
      foreach ($this->tags_array as $one) {
       if(!in_array($one,$arr)){
          $model = new BlogTag();
          $model->blog_id = $this->id;
          $model->tag_id = $one;
          $model->save();
      }
      if(isset($arr[$one])) {
         unset ($arr[$one]);
      }
      }
       BlogTag::deleteAll(['tag_id'=>$arr]);
  }


 }
```

В site.css добавлена запись `.grid-view td > img {max-width: 50px; }`

form.php

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use vova07\imperavi\Widget;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use kartik\widgets\FileInput;





/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model common\models\Blog */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */

?>

<div class="blog-form">

<?php 
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']
]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'text')->widget(Widget::className(), [
    'settings' => [
        'lang' => 'ru',
        'minHeight' => 200,
        #'formatting' =>['p','blockquots', 'h2','h1'],
        'imageUpload' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/site/save-redactor-img','sub'=>'blog']),
        'plugins' => [
            'clips',
            'fullscreen'
        ]
    ]
])?>

<?= $form->field ($model, 'file')->widget(\kartik\file\FileInput::classname(), [
'options'=> ['accept'=> 'image/*'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'showCaption' => false,
        'showRemove' => false,
        'showUpload' => false,
        'browseClass' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block',
        'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
        'browseLabel' =>  'Выбрать фото'
         ],
    ]);?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'url')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'status_id')->dropDownList(\common\models\Blog::STATUS_LIST) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'sort')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'tags_array')->widget(\kartik\select2\Select2::classname(), [
    'data' =>\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\common\models\Tag::find()->all(),'id','name'), 
    'language' => 'ru',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Выбрать tag...','multiple'=> true],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'tags'=>true,
        'maximumInputLength'=> 10
    ],
]); ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

view.php

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use kartik\widgets\ActiveForm; // or yii\widgets\ActiveForm
use kartik\widgets\FileInput;
use yii\grid\GridView;

// or 'use kartik\file\FileInput' if you have only installed 
// yii2-widget-fileinput in isolation
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model common\models\Blog */

$this->title = $model->title;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Blogs', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="blog-view">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ]) ?>
    </p>

    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'title',
            'text:text',
            'url:url',
            'status_id',
            'sort',
            'author.username',
            'author.email',
            'tagsAsString',
            'smallImage:image',
        ],
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте дать разрешение грузить svg.
`[['image'], 'file', 'extensions'=>'jpg, gif, png, svg'],`